# Web scraping with R: can't see the downloadable links

Tags: r, web-scraping, href, rvest

I am trying to download some `.xlsx` files from [this kind of webpage](https://b2share.eudat.eu/records/8d47a255ba5749e3ac169527e22f0068) **EDIT** or [this one](https://b2share.eudat.eu/records/ce32a67a789b44a1a15965fd28a8cb17). However, when I want to display the source code (right click --> view source code), I can't see all the content of the actual webpage (just the header and the footer).

I tried to use the `rvest` to display the downloadable links but same here, it returns only the ones from the header and the footer:

```
library(rvest)
html("https://b2share.eudat.eu/records/8d47a255ba5749e3ac169527e22f0068") %>% 
     html_nodes("a")
```

Returns:

```
#{xml_nodeset (5)}
#[1] <a href="https://eudat.eu">Go to EUDAT website</a>
#[2] <a href="https://eudat.eu"><img src="/img/logo_eudat_cdi.svg" alt="EUDAT CDI logo" style="max-width: 200px"></a>
#[3] <a href="https://www.eudat.eu/eudat-cdi-aup">Acceptable Use #Policy </a>
#[4] <a href="https://eudat.eu/privacy-policy-summary">Data Privacy Statement</a>
#[5] <a href="https://eudat.eu/what-eudat">About EUDAT</a>
```

Any idea how to access the content of the all page?

Comment: This may be hard to do, since the page likely relies on javascript to render. A similar question has been answered for python ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097388/scraping-problem-inspect-element-different-from-view-page-source)), which provides an example of how to piggyback your web browser.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it is very useful. Do you have any idea how to automatically web scrape this kind of page though? There must be a way of doing it I suppose

Comment: Maybe phantomJS could help you with it. Take a look at [this page](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/scraping-dynamic-websites-with-phantomjs/), this could help you out.

Comment: That was a very good tutorial but the problem persists even with phantomjs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the record id to an API endpoint which provides the parts to construct the file download links as follows:

```
library(jsonlite)

d <- jsonlite::read_json('https://b2share.eudat.eu/api/records/8d47a255ba5749e3ac169527e22f0068')

files <- paste(d$links$files, d$files[[1]]$key , sep = '/')
```

For re-use, you can re-write as a function accepting the start link as argument:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(stringr)

get_links <- function(link){
  record_id <- tail(str_split(link, '/')[[1]], 1)
  d <- jsonlite::read_json(paste0('https://b2share.eudat.eu/api/records/', record_id))
  links <- paste(d$links$files, d$files[[1]]$key , sep = '/')
  return(links)
}

get_links('https://b2share.eudat.eu/records/ce32a67a789b44a1a15965fd28a8cb17')
get_links('https://b2share.eudat.eu/records/8d47a255ba5749e3ac169527e22f0068')
```

---

Which you could simplify to:

```
library(jsonlite)

get_links <- function(record_id){
  d <- jsonlite::read_json(paste0('https://b2share.eudat.eu/api/records/', record_id))
  links <- paste(d$links$files, d$files[[1]]$key , sep = '/')
  return(links)
}

get_links('ce32a67a789b44a1a15965fd28a8cb17')
get_links('8d47a255ba5749e3ac169527e22f0068')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I noticed that this is the correct link to DL. The thing is that I have several of this webpages to download the datasets from, and the part that comes after `https://b2share.eudat.eu/api/records/` is always different for each dataset. And in the excel sheet with all the URL to download the data, I only have the URL to the webpage, and not to this downloadable link. So I don't know how to grab this downloadable link from each of the webpages

Comment: Please provide another example link